# Is it correct to introduce yourself as "我是 name"

Tags: names

Can I say "我是 john?" (wo3 shi4 john).

Would it be grammatically correct?

Comment: The grammar is correct. Usually, we use this when somebody asks or calls us. For example, someone asks "誰是John？", and you can answer "我是John。". We use "我叫John" or "我的名字是John" for introduction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a grammatical point of view your sentence is correct. The pattern `我是 + name` is a casual way of introducing yourself. Personally I heard that a lot.
However, in formal situations using the pattern `我叫 + name` is probably the best option.

Like user3a said, I think it's true that the structure `我是 + name` implies that the focus is on 我, whereas in a sentence experessed in the form `我叫 + name` it is your name that receives the focus.